# How to create a category from the most popular occurring value per ID

Tags: python, classification, data-manipulation

I am working with a dataset which consists of a "business rating" for different ice cream shops denoted as 'ID'. In this dataset, we have one observation per day of week per ice cream shop in which we show how busy it is as well as the peak busy hour in a 24 hour format. I would like to create a new column in my dataset that classifies each ice cream shop as one of the following categories: morning, afternoon, and night based on how often it is busy during specific time ranges throughout the week. For instance:

```
If "Time" is between 7 to 10 -> Morning  
If "Time" is between 11 to 14 -> Afternoon  
If "Time" is between 17 to 21 -> Night  
If "Time" is not in these ranges -> None
```

In the event that there is a tie (Ex: Two days are categorized as "Afternoon" and two days as "Night") I would like the classification to be determined by the highest "Busy" rating.

Here is what the dataset looks like:

```
ID   Day        Busy  Time
1    Monday     4.4   18
1    Tuesday    5.0   18
1    Wednesday  6.1   18
1    Thursday   8.3   18
2    Monday     2.5   14
2    Tuesday    4.1   12
2    Wednesday  3.0   13
2    Thursday   3.7   17
3    Monday     5.6   19
3    Tuesday    4.1   18
3    Wednesday  5.4   13
3    Thursday   5.8   12
.
.
.
```

Here is the desired output:

```
ID   Day        Busy  Time  Classification
1    Monday     4.4   18    Night
1    Tuesday    5.0   18    Night
1    Wednesday  6.1   18    Night
1    Thursday   8.3   18    Night
2    Monday     2.5   14    Afternoon
2    Tuesday    4.1   12    Afternoon
2    Wednesday  3.0   13    Afternoon
2    Thursday   3.7   17    Afternoon
3    Monday     5.6   19    Afternoon
3    Tuesday    4.1   18    Afternoon
3    Wednesday  5.4   13    Afternoon
3    Thursday   5.8   12    Afternoon
.
.
.
```

Note: ID 3 has a tie in which Monday and Tuesday would be classified as "Night" and Wednesday and Thursday would be classified as "Afternoon". In this case, we classified this ID as "Afternoon" since the highest "Busy" ranking was 5.8 which corresponds to "Afternoon".

So far, I have successfully created the category column using pd.cut, but I can't achieve this "max occurance" designation to all observations per ID as desired. This is what I have done to create this column:

```
data['Classification'] = pd.cut(data["Time"], bins = [0,6,10,14,16,21,23], labels = ["Off Hours 1", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Off Hours 2", "Night", "Off Hours 3"])
```

However, this provides the following result:

```
ID   Day        Busy  Time  Classification
1    Monday     4.4   18    Night
1    Tuesday    5.0   18    Night
1    Wednesday  6.1   18    Night
1    Thursday   8.3   18    Night
2    Monday     2.5   14    Afternoon
2    Tuesday    4.1   12    Afternoon
2    Wednesday  3.0   13    Afternoon
2    Thursday   3.7   17    Night
3    Monday     5.6   19    Night
3    Tuesday    4.1   18    Night
3    Wednesday  5.4   13    Afternoon
3    Thursday   5.8   12    Afternoon
.
.
.
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter just included my attempt!